# Changing axes ranges on a matplotlib figure returned by PDPBox

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to create ICE/PDP plots for a neural network I have. I was able to make the ICE plots using `PDPBox`. However, when the plots are printed out, the x axes are over a very small range. I know that there are meaningful curves past the point where the x axis ends so I am trying to edit the x (and y) axis range in order to show the full curve. I don't have much experience with `MatPlotLib` and I am struggling to figure this out.

This is the line of code where the plot is created. The `pdp_plot` function returns a matplotlib Figure and 'a dictionary of matplotlib axes'.

`fig,axes=pdp.pdp_plot(ir_pdp_points,'inner radius',plot_lines=True,plot_pts_dist=True)`

I haven't been able to access the axes in a way that I can do anything with them. I've tried things like `fig.add_axes()` and `fig.add_subplot()`, in an attempt to use `set_xlim()`. I just can't seem to understand how to manipulate this thing. The closet I've gotten is printing out a blank plot with the axes I want.

Any help would be so appreciated. Please let me know if you need more info or clarification from me.

Comment: Just extract the [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html) object from the dictionary and use it like normal. Like `axes[0].polt()` to plot data and `axes[0].set_xlabel("x label")`, `axes[0].set_ylabel("y label")` to set label.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out the dictionary that was returned was a dictionary of dictionaries. Once I figured that out, I was able to access the axes object and use it.